# Azure application with different SDK versions on Staging and Production environments

Tags: azure

Can I deploy an azure application to Staging Environment, using the 1.7 SDK, if I have a Production enviroment deployed with a older SDK version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The Staging and Production are totally different environment from runtime perspective so you sure do it.

It actually does not even matter what you want to run on staging and production as the only difference is that with production deployment you have self configured DNS name while the staging give you a GUID based DNS name. Internally they are identical virtual machine configuration as configured in your service still very different to run separately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "staging" and "production" deployments are running on different VMs and are completely independent of each other.